# How to split the specify date range into monthly wise in sql server and loop through each month to perform some operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say if the date is 01/01/2015 till 01/01/2016

I want split these dates monthly format wise and then use them in variable in cursors to loop

For an example Monthly date should be 01/01/2015 and 01/31/2015 and use these two values in 2 variables and make a loop until it never ends whole date range which is 01/01/2016

Comment: Just create a date table that has all the dates you ever need as rows. Makes your life a lot easier -- and maybe you don't even need a loop when you have a table

Comment: Any sample how to do that

Comment: Just use a while loop with a date variable, and insert a new row with every iteration. You'll probably find samples with google but it's not difficult to write

Answer (score 0):

First create a numbers table. This numbers will represent months, days, any thing you need.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 0, 1)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
```

I'll recomend to read this post for extra information https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Then create the list of monthly dates

```
    declare @DateIni datetime, @DateEnd datetime

    set @DateINI='20150101'
    set @DateEnd='20160101'

    select DATEADD(m,n,@dateini) as 'month' from Numbers 
    where n<=DATEDIFF(mm,@dateini,@DateEnd)
```

And Daily dates (notice I changed DATEADD parameter from 'mm' to 'dd')

```
declare @DateIni datetime, @DateEnd datetime

set @DateINI='20150101'
set @DateEnd='20150131'

select DATEADD(dd,n,@dateini) as 'month' from Numbers 
where n<=DATEDIFF(dd,@dateini,@DateEnd)
```